# MySQL index by multiply select

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have two columns in my table `level` and `endtime`, i am selecting needed information with

```
SELECT *, `level` * UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`endtime`) as `bonusTime` 
  FROM `localhost-testing` 
 WHERE `Active` = 1 
 LIMIT 10
```

is it possible to created index for this type of select ?

Comment: Your query is not valid. Please, provide actual query and table structure.

Comment: Indexes are used to process conditions in `ON` and `WHERE` clauses. They're irrelevant to `SELECT` clauses.

Comment: @Barmar: It seems OP is asking 1. whether an INDEX can be defined on an expression. 2. How indexes on columns will affect when they are used in expressions.

Comment: No, it's not possible to create an index for computed values. Indexes only reference the raw data in the table.

Comment: Yes, select with expressions will result a runtime view and we can create indexes on base tables but not views.